# Writing data to model from POST request (Odoo 9.0)

Tags: http-post, odoo, url-routing, odoo-9

I have the following model:

```
class LibraryBook(models.Model):
    _name = 'library.book'
    name = fields.Char('Title', required=True)
    date_release = fields.Date("Release Date")
    author_ids = fields.Many2many("res.partner", string="Authors")
```

I'm new to Odoo and trying to understand the basics of how to save data to my model from a POST request like the following

```
curl -i -X POST --data "name=Odoo%20-%20Much%20Mystery,%20Wow&author_id=Doge" http://0.0.0.0:8069/test
```

I found a way doing this by setting the `csrf` parameter in my controller to `false` like so:

```
[...]
@http.route('/test', type='http', auth='public',methods=['POST'], website=True, csrf=False)
def test(self, **kwargs):
    record = request.env['library.book'].sudo()
    record.create(kwargs)
```

I'm wondering now if there is a way to avoid setting `csrf=false` since I've read that it's a bad idea to do so in general. Also, what would I need to get rid of that `.sudo()`? Not setting `csrf=false` leads to a `400 BAD REQUEST` with `Invalid CSRF token`. Removing `sudo()` leads to a `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`. In *Odoo Development Cookbook* it says in one example with `auth='none'`

> Lack of a user is also why we have to sudo() all our calls to model methods in the example code

Assuming I would expect a POST request from an API, is it possible to associate it with a user so I don't have to `sudo()`?

I would very much appreciate any clarification on this.

**UPDATE**

So I just found [this](https://github.com/osbzr/base/blob/master/odoo/http.py) (line 817):

> - if the form is accessed by an external third party (e.g. REST API   endpoint, payment gateway callback) you will need to disable CSRF
>     protection (and implement your own protection if necessary) by
>     passing the `csrf=False` parameter to the `route` decorator.

which I guess leaves only one question open, regarding `sudo`.

Comment: Working through these types of issues can be frustrating. Have you considered jsonrpc or xmlrpc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SUDO()**

> creates a new environment with the provided user set, uses the administrator if none is provided (to bypass access rights/rules in safe contexts), returns a copy of the recordset it is called on using the new environment:

Odoo does not allow public users to create, update, delete a record.
If we want to create a record from the public users then we need to create a record with the sudo().

**Create record object as administrator**

```
  request.env['library.book'].sudo().create(vals)
```

I hope this may help you.
for more information you can navigate to following links :
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html

Thanks

Comment: How does this ensure that the data came from a legitimate source and not a malicious user? Couldnt someone inject sql commands in the POST?